# R list.files function adds an extra list copying the first list and adding a ~

Tags: r, readxl

I want to read in a folder with 12 xls files and then change one of the colnames so I use

```
liste = list.files("folder")
for(i in seq(liste)){
  x <- read_excel(liste[i])

  
colnames(x)[colnames(x) == "Majority_protein_IDs"] <- "GeneID"
write_xlsx(x,paste("",liste[i],sep = ""))
}
```

however the list value in R then has 13 values:

If the original folder looks like this:

```
sheet1.xlsx
sheet2-xlsx
.
.
.
sheet12.xlsx
```

the value "list" in R then looks like:

```
~sheet1.xlsx
sheet1.xlsx
sheet2.xlsx
.
.
.
sheet12.xlsx
```

Why does it add the extra list with the ~ upfront?

or How can I delete that extra file?

Comment: Can you provide output of `head(liste)`?

Comment: The files are probably there and are probably "hidden". Microsoft Office sometimes uses temporary files starting with a `~` when you open Excel or Word files in Office. Sometimes they don't get deleted even when Office is closed.

Comment: Provide code used for `list.files`. Read about arguments "pattern" and "all.files".

Comment: Seems like you have the excel opened in the background.

Comment: @pbraeutigm Yes that was it however just closing it did not suffice. It appears the first time i ran the code, the excel file was open and anytime i did afterward ( no matter if the file was open or not) the ~file appeared. A pc restart (after going home from work) did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excel file was open the first time I ran the code and as @Gregor Thomas (i don't know if that tag works) pointed out they somtimes don't close even when office is closed.
PC restart and making sure to run the code before opening any of the xlsx files did the trick